# sharing data between two sites ( if the request is valid )

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I'm working on a site and it has a page of documents which should only be accessible to members from another site, and this other site has a page which should only be accessible to members from the site i'm working on.

At the moment this is being done by checking the http referrer, so this other site has a link to say www.mysite.com/for-their-members-page/ and if the http referrer is www.theirsite.com/members/ we know its a valid request from their site from within their members area which they have had to sign into, and the same the other way.

My first concern was the http referrer can easily be faked, but another problem is depending on a users browser or security settings, you might not even get that http referrer.

Is there any solution to this so i can verify if a request is valid - ie that it is coming from this other sites members area? And vice versa, so they can verify that requests to their page are actually coming from members from our site?

Thanks for any help or pointers :)

Comment: Site H = Host of the Data, Site C = Site that wants to share the data. I would setup a webservice on Site H that Site C could use to request a permission key. Site C could then pass the permission key to a gateway page on Site H (through traditional browser request) to allow the user to see the documents

Answer (score 1):

One "safe" solution is to utilize the ColdFusion session variables.

On site A, you need to have a Session variable which identifies a user as logged in (say you have Session.UserName). You then have a simple authentication check page (check.cfm) which does this:

```
<cfif IsDefined("Session.Username")>1<cfelse>0</cfif>
```

Site A links to Site B like this:

```
http://siteB.com/page.cfm?remoteID=<cfoutput>#Session.CFID#&remoteToken=#Session.CFToken#</cfoutput>
```

Now Site B can check whether a user is logged into site A by doing this:

```
<cfhttp url="http://siteA.com/check.cfm?CFID=#URL.remoteID#&CFToken=#URL.remoteToken#"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i like this solution. I'm going to check and tryout the 3 different solutions this weekend and see what works best. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't consider session variables to be safe.  If the same user is on both sites on with different browser tabs, session variables will probably get messed up.

Comment: With what I suggested, the user can be logged in both sides in the same browser and have two separate sessions - he will have two different session identifiers.

Comment: I think xpa1492 is right, i mean, if a single user was on both sites, those sites are on different domains, i wouldn't have thought the session variables would get confused between the two sites ... I'll find out this weekend! Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @user3684025 This is probably the most elegant solution. It nixes link sharing unless you're also sharing login info. It's not as "fun" as my half-mile of code, lol, but it gets the job done pretty nicely. +1

Comment: I really appreciate everyones effort in helping, and especially your 'half-mile' of code :)

Answer (score 0):

To your first question the answer is yes yes yes. A cgi variable can be easily faked and should not be used for any sort of "real" authentication.

Second, there is no sort of "easy" scheme that everyone uses to do what you are tying to do, but there are many "single sign on" solutions that use authentication against a third source. For example, have you ever been to a sight that allows you to sign on with your google or facebook account? They are using oAuth - an SSO standard supported by big social media services.

That's probably overkill for what you are tyring to do, but it's really hard to actually "recommend" something when I don't know what the overall risk is.

For example, you could create a page on server A that is locked down to the IP address of server B (and visa versa). The page could return a UUID - something you create and store in the application scope and rotate every day or hour or 5 minutes (whatever is appropriate for the risk). Then you could store the OTHER servers UUID and refresh it periodically using cfhttp:

```
<cfhttp url="otherserver/myUUID.cfm"/>
<cfset application.otherserveruuid = trim(cfhttp.filecontent)/>
```

Now each server knows 2 things - it's OWN UUID and the OTHER SERVER's UUID.

Finally you append the UUID to the links to the OTHER server and add a check (on the incoming server) to make sure it exists and matches the UUID expected from the server that's coming in.

This scheme would work BUT:

- It's not terribly secure - just harder to fake. For example if you changed the UUID only once per day then someone might simply pass the link around to anyone during the day.
- It's not granular. From your question I take this as what you want. You are not looking to authenticate a specific user. You don't really care WHO they are - you only care that the *come from the other site*.

As long as you understand and can live with those 2 cavaets this would work. As you might imagine there are many other ways to do this. you can probably think of a few :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as i said on the other two answers i'm going to try them out this weekend and see what works best.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this here for whoever might pick something up from it, but [this is the more elegant answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26416295/3917091), and disables link sharing without login sharing.

---

```
<cfif len(trim(Arguments.username)) is "">
  <cfset results.state = 0>
  <cfset results.message = "Username argument is not defined">
  <cfreturn results>
</cfif>

<cfif len(trim(Arguments.password)) is "">
  <cfset results.state = 0>
  <cfset results.message = "Password argument is not defined">
  <cfreturn results>
</cfif>

<cfif not isDefined("Arguments.CustID")>
  <cfset results.state = 0>
  <cfset results.message = "Customer ID (representing the user of your site) is required.">
  <cfreturn results>
</cfif>

<cfquery name="ValidateSite"...>
  select SiteID from othersites
   where username = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.username#">
   where password = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.password#">
     and Active = 1
</cfquery>

<cfif ValidateSite.recordcount eq 1>
  <cfset results.Passkey = Hash(Arguments.username & "_" & Arguments.custID)>
  <!--- I chose hash because it will reliably create the same key when the referring site provides the same data. Wheras, a lot of other functions might not. --->
  <cfquery name="CheckID"...>
    Select SiteID
      from PermKeys
     where SiteID=<cfparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ValidateSite.siteID#">
       and PassKey=<cfparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#results.PassKey#">
       and custID=<cfparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Arguments.custID#">)
  </cfquery>
  <cfif CheckID.recordcount eq 0>
    <cfquery...>
      insert into PermKeys(SiteID,Passkey,CustID)
      values(<cfparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ValidateSite.siteID#">,<cfparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#results.PassKey#">,<cfparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Arguments.custID#">)
    </cfquery>
    <cfset results.message = "Authentication for this customer created.">
  <cfelse>
    <cfset results.message = "Authentication for this customer previously created. Authentication Key will always be the same. Please store the authentication keys, passed back as passKey, on your own server so that a call isn't needed each time.">
  </cfif>
  <cfset results.state = 1>
  <cfset results.siteID = ValidateSite.siteID>
  <cfset results.custID = Arguments.custID>
<cfelse>
  <cfset results.state = 0>
  <cfset results.message = "User not found.">
</cfif>
<cfreturn results>
```

This would return, if successful

- State of 1.
- SiteID, a numeric ID
- PassKey, unique to each custID
- CustID (as passed by Arguments.custID). Not actually needed in this example.
- A message.

If site credential validation fails or is inaccurately provided, this returns

- State of 0.
- A message explaining why.

And then I'd invoke the webservice, get credentials for the user and return a link like

http://docssite.com/authorize/index.cfm?site=#siteID#&passkey=#passkey#&customerID=#custID#

Index.cfm of authorize would check those three url params against PermKeys, make sure it's legit, and log the user IN. You could even directly pass docIDs in the urls and use that decision as whether or not to display the docID.

If you were also passing a docID in the list, you could easily just cfhttp to the same url with all the params and get the document returned.

You could then write a similar webservice to delete expired credentials (say someone unsubscribed from customer site, you wouldn't want their credentials to still work).

The customer site could (and should) keep track of users they've already invoked the webservice for, and hold their passkey and CustID (unique to each customer) in their own database so that they didn't need to make repeated calls to your webservice for the same information.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I'm going to check out the various solutions this weekend and see what works best.